# JavaScript: Search and replace string in external script

Tags: javascript, replace

I am running this cool product widget (show-space) on my website that puts selected products on there. It uses the following script:

```
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    var fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        js  = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://www.show-space.com/widgets/manager.js?api_key=0qslzweoj79lp7h03ki9";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, "script", "showspace-manager-js"));
</script>
```

which is called by something like this: `[ss-widget id=my_widget]`

The problem I am encountering now is that the widget (which is no longer supported) uses USD ("$") for all the product widgets while I prefer to show them in Swedish Krona ("kr"), which is typically placed after the number.

I would prefer:
a. change "$99" to "99 kr"
but
b. change "$99" to "SEK 99" 
would work as well

I hardly know any JavaScript but was told that this could be solved with a JavaScript. So, what can I do in order to fix this?

Example on how the widget looks like: http://www.presenttips.se/fars-dag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex, personally.

with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contents=$('#my_widget').html();
    var rgx=/\$\s?(\d*(?:\.\d{2})?)/g;
    $('#my_widget').html(contents.replace(rgx,"$1 kr"));
});
```

With vanilla:

```
var contents=document.getElementById("my_widget").innerHTML;
var rgx=/\$\s?(\d*(?:\.\d{2})?)/g;
document.getElementById("my_widget").innerHTML=contents.replace(rgx,"$1 kr"));
```

Notes:

This looks for prices in the following forms:

$20

$ 20

$20.50

$ 20.50

Some examples of prices it would not find:

$      20

$20.999

$20.9

with the vanilla version you'll need an event to trigger the javascript. This will likely be the body loading, so you'll have something in your script tag like:

```
body.onload=function() {
var content=...
...
};
```

Edit: I've had a look at your page and can see (at least in that particular case) that your widget is defined by class name, rather than id. I've made the following change to the vanilla script and it works fine on the page you've linked - BUT you should be aware that in this implementation it will only work on the first occurrence of the widget it finds on each page... I think you are unlikely to have more than one to a page anyway, so it should be no biggie.

Works on your page:

```
var contents=document.getElementsByClassName("ss-widget")[0].innerHTML;
var rgx=/\$\s?(\d*(?:\.\d{2})?)/g;
document.getElementsByClassName("ss-widget")[0].innerHTML=contents.replace(rgx,"$1 kr");
```

Final edit:
As the above is shown to fudge some other things in the widget, here's the working, jQuerified version including event handler registration and script tags

```
<script> 
    jQuery(document).ready( //When the document is ready, run the following function...
        function(){
            jQuery('.ss-widget .product-price').each( //Pick everything with class product-price inside everything with class ss-widget and run the following function on each
                function() {
                    var contents=jQuery(this).html(); //Get the contents of this element
                    var rgx=/\$\s?(\d*(?:\.\d{2})?)/g; //Define a regex to search for a dollar sign, followed by an optional space, followed by an arbitary amount of digits, optionally followed by a decimal plus 2 digits. Group everything but the dollar sign and space.
                    jQuery(this).html(contents.replace(rgx,"$1 kr")); //Replace any text found by the regex with it's grouped result, a space, then the text kr.
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: You are the hero of the day! I had to use window.onload instead of body.onload since I use a high-end Wordpress theme that won't give you access to the HTML in an easy way. Thanks!!

Comment: Wait, it does the trick but it crashes the script somehow making it impossible to scroll inside the widget (the right button)... Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: ...I am thinking that what you mentioned "it will only work on the first occurrence of the widget it finds on each page" is the reason why this doesn't work? When I interact with the widget, it seems "dead", it should have hover images and be possible to scroll by clicking the right arrow.

Comment: I'm not 100% why this has happened, My guess is that there was some event handler added by show-space's api that we triggered. I had a brief look but trying to debug uglified js makes me cry, so I have a workaround for you instead. 
`jQuery('.ss-widget .product-price').each(function() {
contents=jQuery(this).html();
var rgx=/\$\s?(\d*(?:\.\d{2})?)/g;
jQuery(this).html(contents.replace(rgx,"$1 kr"));
});`
On the happy side, looking at the script told me that your page supports jQuery, which makes the whole thing breezy. When I run that script your hover images and scrolling is unaffected.

Comment: THANKS! Now, it finally worked! It took me some time to understand exactly how to implement the code. Could you put this in your full answer for others who might search for the same solution: <script>
window.onload=function() {
jQuery('.ss-widget .product-price').each(function() { contents=jQuery(this).html(); var rgx=/\$\s?(\d*(?:\.\d{2})?)/g; jQuery(this).html(contents.replace(rgx,"$1 kr")); });
};
</script>

Comment: if I were you, I would instead use `jQuery(document).ready(`. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for some reason. It seems like the script never runs, like it doesn't act upon .ready(). Any ideas?

Comment: Not really, it's tough to tell exactly what the issue would be because running code on document ready is not something I can do in browser at your site. Some possibilities are going to be that the script tag in which you put your code is located earlier in the document then the script tag which loads jQuery, or that a later script tag overrides the ready event handler (which is strange behavior, granted). There'll be an error in the javascript console that tells you exactly why though, I'm guessing.